# Explain example pipeline from Python subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

Section [17.1.4.2: Replacing shell pipeline](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) of the python subprocess module says to replace

```
output=`dmesg | grep hda`
```

with

```
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

The comment to the third line explains why the close function is being called, but not why it makes sense. It doesn't, to me. Will not closing p1.stdout before the communicate method is called prevent *any* output from being sent through the pipe? (Obviously it won't, I've tried to run the code and it runs fine). *Why* is it necessary to call close to make p1 receive SIGPIPE? What kind of close is it that doesn't close? What, exactly, is it closing?

Please consider this an academic question, I'm not trying to accomplish anything except understanding these things better.

Comment: stdin and stdout are files. So you're supposed to close them to free the pipe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are closing `p1.stdout` in the *parent* process, thus leaving dmesg as the only process with that file descriptor open.  If you didn't do this, even when dmesg closed its stdout, you would still have it open, and a `SIGPIPE` would not be generated.  (The OS basically keeps a reference count, and generates `SIGPIPE` when it hits zero.  If you don't close the file, you prevent it from ever reaching zero.)